# Running Sonar from command line without a SonarQube server

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I need to perform some static analysis of java classes from command line To extract basic metrics and I was thinking I could use sonar-cli, but that required a fully working SonarQube.

How can I perform those inspections?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to get the metrics on your code, then there's no other choice than installing a SonarQube server and indeed run an analysis using a SonarQube scanner.

By the way, installing a SQ server for such a simple use case is as simple as extracting the binaries from the ZIP archive and double-click on the sonar.sh or sonar.bat scripts. See ["Get Started in Two Minutes" documentation page](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Get+Started+in+Two+Minutes).

Comment: Another option would be to use the [SonarQube Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/sonarqube/).

Comment: I went the SonarQube docker container route.  Took about 30 min to get it up and running.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the information. I am thinking to purchase SonarQube for our usage. Basically we have quite a large number of C code (small programs; within 200 LOC) and I want to quantify each C code regarding complexity, code smells, etc. Can SQ be launched via command line? Or I will have to use mouse/browser to do all the tasks which seem quite tedious?

Comment: Docker way:
run `docker run -d --name sonarqube -e SONAR_ES_BOOTSTRAP_CHECKS_DISABLE=true -p 9000:9000 sonarqube:latest`
go to `localhost:9000` in browser
login with admin:admin and go to My Account -> Security -> Tokens and generate new one
use it in your build - e.g.: mvn org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar -Dsonar.login=...